# Possible to develop google chrome extension with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome-extension

I'm not sure why its telling me that this question is subjective. I've looked all over the internet and cant find an answer. I know that content scripts for google chrome extensions are commonly written in javascript.

What is the link between this and Ruby? I know Rails is a web development framework for Ruby. I am just learning about all of this stuff.

Answer (score 10):

Ruby on Rails is a framework for server-side code in the Ruby language.
Chrome extensions are written in pure Javascript.
And never the twain shall meet.

You may want to use CoffeeScript, which is a Ruby-like language which is transformed to Javascript.
(I've never tried writing Chrome extensions in it, but I assume it will work correctly)

Comment: technically speaking you could create a web service in ruby on rails and use ajax to call on it from your chrome extension.

Comment: @Kyle: However, the extension would still be written in Javascript.

Comment: but what about the server? my extension needs to access a server that needs some code on it. So could I have the extension access it in javascript but my server could be controlled with ruby on rails? Is this a mistake. Would it be easier to code my server with something else like php?

Comment: @user1123905: The server language doesn't matter at all.  Use whatever you want, as long as it supports HTTP.

Comment: ok so basically I write all of the clint side programming in javascript and then the server side programming in whatever, and then the way the communicate is strictly through mySQL statments?

Comment: @user1123905 Correct about client side / server side... but the two communicate via AJAX calls.  The extension makes an AJAX call to the server, the server processes it (using SQL statements if need be) and then returns a response to the extension to show to the user.

Comment: Just a so you know, that might change. According to this: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/05/running-client-side-ruby-on-the-web-with-native-client-or-emscripten/ its possible to run ruby on a NaCI compat browser (chrome). I don't know if this means that it WILL happen but at least it's now a possibility and possibilities are always good. Slightly related, With the volt framework you can now use ruby for front end goodness instead of javascript (well it actually translates ruby to js with opal) but volt is still not quite there but it's definitely something to watch.